# Android generating a hash string sha256

Tags: android, hash

I'm trying to encrypt a url-request, username and password, then post it to a webpage.

But for some reason eclipse is saying the syntax is wrong, what am I doing wrong?
It is the bit at the bottom where it says `md.update` that is causing errors.

Here's my code so far:

```
private static final String apiKey = "38m8nyev284nddci49940303094"; 
private static final String apiUser = "esdt34ds"; 

long unixTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

String newFeedRequest = "1.0/evoStructure?timestamp=" + unixTimeStamp;
String fixturesFeedURL = "https://secure.website.com/_services/api/" + newFeedRequest;

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");


md.update(fixturesFeedURL.getBytes("UTF-8"),apiKey.getBytes("UTF-8"),apiUser.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Change this to "UTF-16" if needed
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Syntax error, insert "Type VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList
> - Syntax error on token "update", Identifier expected after this token
> - Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead
> - Syntax error on token ",", @ expected
> - Syntax error on token ",", @ expected

Comment: Would probably help if you say what the error is you're receiving.

Answer (score 1):

That's a cryptic error. But I'd say your not using correct parameters for update()

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html

The API shows update(ByteBuffer), update(byte[], int, int), update(byte[]), update(byte). Don't see any that take (byte[], byte[], byte[]) try calling

`md.update(fixturesFeedURL.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

`md.update(apiKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

`md.update(apiUser.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

instead